# mysql how to update a foreign key automatically

Tags: mysql, relational-database

this is my tables

```
 CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `carslibrary` (
      `CarID` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
      `CarName` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
      PRIMARY KEY (`CarID`)
    ) ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 AUTO_INCREMENT=4 ;

    CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `colorslibrary` (
      `ColorID` int(11) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
      `ColorName` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
      PRIMARY KEY (`ColorID`)
    ) ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 AUTO_INCREMENT=5 ;


    CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `facerecord` (
      `carslibrary_ID` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL,
      `colorslibrary_ID` int(11) unsigned NOT NULL,
      KEY `carslibrary_ID` (`carslibrary_ID`),
      KEY `colorslibrary_ID` (`colorslibrary_ID`)
    ) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;
```

i noticed carslibrary_ID attribute inside facerecord table is not automatically updated when i add a car record inside carslibrary table, what should i do to be able to?

Comment: How can you have a record auto added to facerecord when you insert a carslibrary record when you only have 1/2 the information. To me the facerecord table looks like a relationship table of cars -> colors.

Comment: colorslibrary_ID is updated manually while carslibrary_ID shouldn't

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Firstly, you'll need to have a default value specified for the `facerecord.colorslibrary_ID` since you will not 'know' what it is when inserting into the `carslibrary` table. That said you could alter your DDL for the `facerecord` table to be:

```
CREATE TABLE `facerecord` (
`carslibrary_ID` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL,
`colorslibrary_ID` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
KEY `carslibrary_ID` (`carslibrary_ID`),
KEY `colorslibrary_ID` (`colorslibrary_ID`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;
```

I've also changed the datatype of the `colorslibrary_ID` column to match that of the `colorslibrary.ColorID` column in case you ever feel like setting up a foreign key between `facerecord.colorslibrary_ID` and `colorslibrary.ColorID` ;). For the sake of completeness you should insert a row into the `colorslibrary` table with a ColorID = 0. Hence:

```
insert into `colorslibrary` (ColorName) values ('unknown color');

update `colorslibrary` set ColorID = 0 where ColorName = 'unknown color';
```

Then you can go ahead and define your trigger to insert into the `facerecord` table:

```
delimiter $$

CREATE TRIGGER carslibrary_trigger
    AFTER insert ON carslibrary
    FOR EACH ROW
    BEGIN
      insert into facerecord (carslibrary_ID) values (new.CarID);
END$$

delimiter;
```

All new rows inserted into the `facerecord` table will then be inserted with a `colorslibrary_ID` that relates to the 'unknown color' `colorslibrary.ColorName`.You can then manually update the `facerecord.colorslibrary_ID` as and when you know it.

Good luck!

PS If you need to remove any existing `AFTER insert` triggers from the carslibrary table you can do so by firstly finding the existing triggers:

```
select trigger_name
from information_schema.triggers
where event_object_table = 'carslibrary'
and action_timing = 'AFTER'
and event_manipulation= 'INSERT';
```

Then take the name of the trigger returned by the above statement (lets say the string 'carslibrary_trigger' is returned) and run:

```
drop trigger carslibrary_trigger;
```

Then re-run the `CREATE TRIGGER` script.

Once a trigger is set up it will automatically perform the action you have specified when the trigger action you have specified occurs. In this case we are telling the database "after an insert happens into the carslibrary table automatically insert a row into the `facerecord` table using the `CarID` of the new `carslibrary` row to populate the `facerecord.carslibrary_ID` column". As with most things the best way is to try it! Once you have created the trigger manually insert a new row into the 'carslibrary`table. Now look at the data in the`facerecord` table - you should see a new row that has been inserted by the trigger firing.

It sounds like you would benefit from learning about triggers. I recommend the docs on the [MySQL site](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/create-trigger.html) because this answer is *way* longer than I first intended it to be!

Comment: how do i actually use the triggers? i pasted it in the sql text area and i am getting error: MySQL said: 

#1235 - This version of MySQL doesn't yet support 'multiple triggers with the same action time and event for one table'

Comment: sounds like you already have a trigger set up for insert on the carslibrary table. You'll need to drop these if you want to set up the trigger above. I've amended my answer with some more info for you.

Comment: Notice that  insert into facerecord (carslibrary_ID) values (new.CarID); , the new should actually be NEW.

Answer (score 0):

You will need to use triggers. See http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/triggers.html