# How to update or insert a child table which having foreign key constrains from parent table

Tags: mysql, sql, foreign-keys, constraints

I have below two parent-(UserLogins,UserSecurityQuestions) and one child table - UserSecurityAnswers

```
#Parent Table
CREATE TABLE UserLogins
(
    UserLoginID SMALLINT NOT NULL IDENTITY(1,1),
    UserLogin VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
    UserPassword VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL,
    CONSTRAINT pk_UL_UserLoginID PRIMARY KEY(UserLoginID)
);


CREATE TABLE UserSecurityQuestions
(
    UserSecurityQuestionID TINYINT NOT NULL IDENTITY(1,1),
    UserSecurityQuestion VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
    CONSTRAINT pk_USQ_UserSecurityQuestionID PRIMARY KEY(UserSecurityQuestionID)
);
```

#Child Table

```
CREATE TABLE UserSecurityAnswers
(
    UserLoginID SMALLINT NOT NULL IDENTITY(1,1),
    UserSecurityAnswers VARCHAR(25) NOT NULL,
    UserSecurityQuestionID TINYINT NOT NULL,
    CONSTRAINT pk_USA_UserLoginID PRIMARY KEY(UserLoginID), 
    CONSTRAINT fk_UL_UserLoginID FOREIGN KEY(UserLoginID) REFERENCES UserLogins(UserLoginID),
    CONSTRAINT fk_USQ_UserSecurityQuestionID FOREIGN KEY(UserSecurityQuestionID) REFERENCES UserSecurityQuestions(UserSecurityQuestionID)
);
```

#INsert value in to parent table

```
#UserLogins 
insert into UserLogins values('User1', 'Pass1');
insert into UserLogins values('User2', 'Pass2');
insert into UserLogins values('User3', 'Pass3');
insert into UserLogins values('User4', 'Pass4');
insert into UserLogins values('User5', 'Pass5');

#UserSecurityQuestions 
insert into UserSecurityQuestions values('What is your favourite food?');
insert into UserSecurityQuestions values('What is your favourite food?');
insert into UserSecurityQuestions values('What is your favourite food?');
insert into UserSecurityQuestions values('What is your favourite food?');
insert into UserSecurityQuestions values('What is your favourite food?');
```

Now i am updating table UserSecurityAnswers with below value

```
insert into UserSecurityAnswers values('Apples');
insert into UserSecurityAnswers values('Spiderman');
insert into UserSecurityAnswers values('School1');
insert into UserSecurityAnswers values('Ram');
insert into UserSecurityAnswers values('Toyota');
```

But i am getting below error

```
Column name or number of supplied values does not match table definition.
```

i expected child table would inherited values from parent table in this case. but not sure what wrong with this implementation

Any help on this ?

Comment: 'i expected child table would inherited values from parent table ' - FK's don't pull or push data ie no inheritance happens.

Comment: This is a faq. Please before considering posting: Pin down code issues via [mre]. Read manuals/references & google error messages & many clear, concise & precise phrasings of your question/problem/goal, with & without your particular names/strings/numbers, 'site:stackoverflow.com' & tags; read many answers. SO/SE search is poor & literal & unusual, read the help. Google re googling/searching, including Q&A at [meta] & [meta.se]. [How much research effort is expected of Stack Overflow users?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/261592/3404097) [ask] [Help]. Reflect research in posts.

Comment: This has the code part of a [mre]. But: When you get a result you don't expect, pause your overall goal, chop to the 1st subexpression with unexpected result & say what you expected & why, justified by documentation. (Debugging fundamental.)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [mysql how to update a foreign key automatically](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7670662/mysql-how-to-update-a-foreign-key-automatically)

Comment: You have tagged your question with `mysql` but your DDL looks like SQL Server. Please correct the tagging of your question. Try to think logically about your statement - `i expected child table would inherited values from parent table`. If you tell the server you want to insert `Apples`, how could it possibly know which `UserLogin` and/or `UserSecurityQuestion` you want it to be associated with?

Answer (score 0):

Only the Primary keys will be taken automatically during insert if its given as increment.
All other columns you have to supply, if you just given "Apply" the db doesnt know to map it against the parent FK id.

In your insert query into Answers table, include the PK value from other two tables.

btw- you are not updating the securityanswer table, you are trying to insert fresh. So the FK columns are mandatory.